Embeded webview (local) bundled with android application shows index.html instead of home ('/')
I built web application with React.js.
To create android webview application, I moved that package into assets directory in android project to bundle them.
However, when I build android project and run it on my device, it shows me 'android_assets/index.html' page instead of my home page which is ('/').
I followed official android developer guide: https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/webapps/load-local-content
To load my web application package with Url, I wrote code like below in my 'onCreate' function:
mywebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
When I build and run it on my device, it shows page with url path '/android_asset/index.html'/ instead of '/'. (I created custome route with 'Route' and 'Routes' component from 'react-router-dom' package)
I have bottom bar with buttons which can take me to home. When I click that button, it take me to hoeme.
All the functions and views are working fine except initial page is not '/'.
I want my webview application to show home with address '/' instead of 'android_asset/index.html'.

What is it that you would see if all went ok for '/'? And who would deliver the html source? Would it come from assets too? How did you store it there,? Si what is home exactly,?

#1.Currently my app shows 'index.html' which is just blank page. Only ' is there.
#2.When I was developing web application first, it took me to home which path is '/' when it runs.
#3.My html sources are in '/src/main/assets/' in my android project.
#4.I stored them by moving my web application package after built it.
#5.'Home' is the web component written in javascrip using React.js library. I named it 'home' because it should appear first when app is running.

You did not answer my questions.

Somehow I solved my problem! Thank you for your interest!
